# Interpreting cubic splines graph where plot doesn't go to final knot

Tags: r, interpretation, splines, ggplot2

I have this plot where I found that the best degree of freedom is 8, as it minimizes the SSE when predicted from the training data. However, the graph does not go into the final 8th knot in the spline. Am I doing something wrong with how I am plotting? Or if I am not, what is happening?

```
xlims_sample2_test<-range(sample2_test$x)
x.grid_sample2_test<-seq(from=xlims_sample2_test[1], to = xlims_sample2_test[2])
sample2_test_fit <- lm(y ~ ns(x, df = 8), data = sample2_test)
sample2_test_pred<-predict(sample2_test_fit, newdata = data.frame(x = x.grid_sample2_test), se = T)

ggplot(sample2_test, aes(x = x, y = y))  + geom_point(pch = 1)+
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x.grid_sample2_test, sp = sample2_test_pred$fit), 
            aes(x = x.grid_sample2_test, y = sp), color = "red")+
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x.grid_sample2_test, ub = sample2_test_pred$fit + 2*sample2_test_pred$se), 
            aes(x = x.grid_sample2_test, y = ub), linetype = 2,color="black",lwd=0.65) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x.grid_sample2_test, lb = sample2_test_pred$fit - 2*sample2_test_pred$se), 
            aes(x = x.grid_sample2_test, y = lb), linetype = 2,color="black",lwd=0.65) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = attributes(ns(sample2_test$x, df = 8))$knots, 
             linetype = "dashed", color = "grey30")+
  labs(title = "Cubic Spline of sample 2 testing, df = 8")
```

[image]

Comment: Using `ns` with $8$ degrees of freedom fits a spline with a total of $9$ knots: $2$ boundary knots and $7$ internal knots. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/517479/21054) for example.

Comment: There shouldn't be sharp corners in a spline fit like this. The whole point is to make the fit appear to be smooth. Looks like something is wrong in your code somewhere. Providing a minimal reproducible example with data would help a lot.

Comment: On your 2nd line, inside your `seq()` function, try adding the argument `length.out = 1000` or something. Right now `x.grid_sample2_test` only has something like 7 or 8 distinct values, so you only evaluate `predict()` at these few x-values, so `geom_line()` is just connecting them with straight line segments. That's why you don't see the spline's actual curvature, and might also explain why the right end of the spline is missing.